# Why can't I connect to our backend server in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, request, frontend, middleware

I am a frontend developer and we are developing a mobile app for the company with my R&D team. We were working with a local backend server, then the backend developer decided to migrate the project into the server of our company. There is no problem while I am working in the office, but when I am working from home, I can't connect the server through my React Native App.

I can connect the server with VPN through my browser and use Swagger to get to the data. I can also use Postman to send requests to the server. But it is not working on my application. I am confused because I thought React Native was supposed to work since it is sending the requests through my computer. I have also tried to send requests using the Android Studio Emulator but it also does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What do you mean it is not working? Please provide some more information.

Comment: When I try to send a request, it does not return anything no errors and success messages @AriadniMak

Answer (score 0):

The emulator you are using is not connected to your computer network, try creating a new emulator it will automatically be wired to your network and also VPN, or try installing openVpnConnect and use it on the emulator or real device